# How can I create multiple bookmarks in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

it's my first time here and I hope you can help me, I want to recreate the following scenario:
The code is written in mustache and generates a loop to fetch titles and details

```
{#Titles}
{/}

{#Titles}
{#details}
{/}
{/}
```

---- This results in the following --

```
Title A
Title B
Title C

Title A
details

Title B
details

Title C
details
```

---

How can I create multiple bookmarks so that when I press Titles A it goes to Title A and its detail?

I understand you could have something like **[bookmark_1][bookmark_2][bookmark_3**]... etc

```
Title A -> [bookmark_1]
Title B -> [bookmark_2]
Title C -> [bookmark_3]

Title A [bookmark_1]
title details

Title B [bookmark_2]
title details

Title C [bookmark_3]
title details
```

Comment: Do you just mean creating a Table of Contents? Make the Titles Heading 1 format...?

Comment: Sure, I would like to make a table of contents, but without indicator numbers (1. Title A, 2. Title B), I would like (Title A ... , Title B...) But note that I have a loop with mustache :

{#Titles}
{/}

{#Titles}
{#details}
{/}
{/}

Comment: Is this a question then about `mustache` or VBA?  What have you tried?